# how can I create separate redis subscriber for each user-websocket connection on spring boot

Tags: spring, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe

[image]I create a chat, there are two services, the chat service is responsible for the ws connection and redirects new messages to kafka, the chat-store-service receives new messages from kafka, saves them to the database and publishes them to RedisStream, then the chat service redis subscriber receives this message and sends it via ws, how can I store the state of each user, for example, which messages have been read and which have not been read, is he online? I'm thinking of creating a separate redis subscriber for each user, but I don't understand how to do it. Also I think, I need to open new channel(redis stream) for each chat

my config

```
@Value("${spring.data.redis.pubsub.topic}")
private String redisPubSubTopic;

@Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
private String redisHost;

@Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
private Integer redisPort;

@Bean
public ChannelTopic topic() {
    return new ChannelTopic(redisPubSubTopic);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}

@Bean("jedisConnectionFactory")
public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    configuration.setHostName(redisHost);
    configuration.setPort(redisPort);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
}
@Configuration
public class RedisSubscriberConfig {

private final MessageListener messageListener;
private final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

public RedisSubscriberConfig(
        @Qualifier("messageSubscriber") MessageListener messageListener,
        @Qualifier("jedisConnectionFactory") RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory
) {
    this.messageListener = messageListener;
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(messageListener);
}

@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer(
        ChannelTopic topic
) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(messageListener, topic);
    return container;
}
```

}

Comment: you are saying that the chat service redirect new message to kafka. I was wondering why you don't directly emit new message on redis rather than doing that from the queue in kafka. Is that for not overloading the server ?